# Plant growth regulators for Grape berry elongation?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I want to make a formulation for grape berry elongation, planning to use

- GA3,
- NATCA (N Acetyl Thiolidine Carboxylic Acid),
- IAA (Indole-3-acetic acid),
- IBA (Indole-3-butyric acid)

What else can I use?

Ultimate goal is to increase auxin level in plants.

All auxins are compounds with aromatic ring and a carboxylic acid group so will it be helpful to use carboxylic acids as a solvent with the above plant growth regulators?

Comment: While near everything from cosmology to psychology is about chemistry this way or another, chemists are rarely the best choice to ask about it. // I assume such a specific targetting is more matter of genetics than of growth regulators.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Actually I am new to this site,

Answer (score -1):

For any elongation like purpose for example elongation of sugarcane, apple, grape etc we use gibberellins.

You can get this result by just a single Google search.

My source: Biology NCERT Class 11 chapter 15 (2021 edition) and [this site](https://www.biotech-asia.org/vol16no1/proteomic-analysis-of-ga3-induced-berry-elongation-in-grape-vitis-vinifera-l-cultivar-thompson-seedless/#:%7E:text=ABSTRACT%3A%20GA3%20is%20a,Seedless%20(Vitis%20vinifera%20L.))

Comment: Actually I am new to this site, I have used GA3 + NATCA N Acetyl Thiolidine Carboxylic Acid + IAA Indole-3-acetic acid + IBA Indole-3-butyric acid all these are dissolved in aceton & water. ok results, is there more pGRs I can use?